Selenium throwing "WebDriverException: Message: no such execution context" after clicking on element
I am working on a script for a class and I execute this code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import time

x = random.randrange(1, 16)
i = f"mntl-recipe-card-meta_{x}-0"
url = "https://www.eatingwell.com/recipes/17947/mealtimes/dinner/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

link = driver.find_element(By.ID, i)
link.click()

time.sleep(2)

current_url = driver.execute_script("return window.location.href;")

print("Current URL:", current_url)
driver.quit()

The code works up until it has to click on the link, then it throws a error that says "WebDriverException: Message: no such execution context". The error seems to be thrown after I click on the link as the program stops working as the new page is loading in. I want to be able to do things after I click on the element so this stops the program from working.

It works fine for me. Are you sure this is the exact code you are trying to run? No differences? Are you just trying to get the URL from the links?

Your posted code worked fine for me. I made a few changes to show you some potential improvements, if you find them useful... and maybe it will fix the issue for you.

You can grab all of the recipe links on the page using a CSS selector
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='mntl-card-list-items_']")


By using #1, we have a list of all of such links on the page and we can use random.choice() to pick a random item from the list instead of inserting a random number 1-16 (which doesn't get all of the links).
link = random.choice(links)


Right now all your code does is click the link and then grab the URL after navigating. If all you want is the URL, you can grab that off the front page without clicking.
print(link.get_attribute("href"))


If you want the current URL in the browser, you don't need the JavaScript... you can just use
current_url = driver.current_url


You don't need the sleep


The full working code is
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random

url = "https://www.eatingwell.com/recipes/17947/mealtimes/dinner/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='mntl-card-list-items_']")
link = random.choice(links)
print(link.get_attribute("href"))
link.click()

current_url = driver.current_url

print("Current URL:", current_url)

